# View Controller loses connection to constraints in IBOutlets when switching tabs in UITabView

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, iboutlet

OK, so here's the relevant bit of my code:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionView: QuestionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerView: AnswerView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // Active at start, attaches tableView.topAnchor to questionView.bottomAnchor
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopAlternateConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // Inactive at start, attaches tableView.topAnchor to answerView.bottomAnchor
    
    func submitAnswer() {
        tableViewTopConstraint.isActive = false
        tableViewTopAlternateConstraint = true
    }
    
    func newQuestion() {
        tableViewTopConstraint.isActive = true
        tableViewTopAlternateConstraint = false
    }
}
```

I'm building a question/answer type of app and the two subviews are different sizes for design reasons.  I have it set so that it toggles between the two subviews depending on the current state (toggling back for a new question when the user taps to advance), and it works fine...

...until I go to a different tab on the `UITabView` that encloses everything (e.g. to change the settings then resume testing)

The moment the tab changes it's like the `NSLayoutConstraint` outlets no longer exist.  The orders to change them still process (I've verified this in the console), but they do nothing.

- I've tried declaring the outlets as strong *(there was no difference in behavior)*
- I've removed the outlets and managed them in code *(it worked the first time, but afterward it stretched the shorter `QuestionView`'s height to match `tableView`'s new top position instead of moving `tableView` up to the bottom of `QuestionView` as was intended)*
- I've tried implementing a `UITabViewController` so that I could call `tabBar(_:didSelect:)` and replace the view controller with a brand new instance of `MyViewController()` whenever I switch back to that tab *(It loads the first time, but when I try to switch tabs it finds `nil` when accessing any of the `IBOutlet`s...even though I didn't tap on the tab for the testing view and filtered by `item.tag` when replacing the existing view controller)*

Any suggestions on how else to attack this problem?

Comment: *"here's the relevant bit of my code"* ... you may *think* that's the relevant bit, but it's not. You haven't shown anything you might be doing anywhere else (such as in `viewDidAppear()`?). Start a fresh project with a tab bar controller and two view controllers. In the first one, add a view and a button, with top constraints for the view connected to `@IBOutlet`s, with only the bare minimum code needed to test it.

Comment: Just update the constraints once you get back to the tab

Comment: By the way... `@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopAlternateConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // Inactive at start` --- how is it "inactive at start"?

Comment: @DonMag The inactive constraint has the "Installed" checkbox unchecked if you select it in Interface Builder.  As such the first of the two constraints is the only one active (and IB doesn't register a conflict between them, even though `tableView` would have two conflicted values otherwise).

Comment: @Kaji - un-checking "Installed" means *"DO NOT install this constraint at run-time*" ... which is, obviously, not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't set `@IBOutlet` properties to `weak`. I know that's the default, but it's not correct.

If you have this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopAlternateConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

connected to a constraint via Storyboard, and you do this:

```
tableViewTopAlternateConstraint.isActive = false
```

you just ***removed*** that constraint from existence.

In addition, if you have two different Top constraints in Storyboard, you should be getting an Error indicator as they cannot be satisfied.

Better to either change the Priorities, or use a single constraint and change the `.constant` value.

So, two constraints in Storyboard:

- set the "default" constraint to `Priority: High (750)`
- set the "alternate" constraint to `PriorityL Low (250)`

and your code becomes:

```
func submitAnswer() {
    tableViewTopConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
    tableViewTopAlternateConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
}

func newQuestion() {
    tableViewTopAlternateConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
    tableViewTopConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights!  My program I'm working on is still having the issue, however I started with a fresh build in a new project and built in all of the components discussed and the proof-of-concept is working properly.  Based on that I'm giving this a checkmark and may see about porting my code into the proof of concept app setup to see if I can identify what the underlying issue is along the way.